# Setting a value to a textlabel of a table row displays the same value multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am fetching records from core data in `viewDidLoad` method as follows,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


    if (result.count > 0) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < [result count]; i++) {
            NSManagedObject *pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:i];

            statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"], nil];
            amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];
        }
```

Now the `amountArray` has got two different values.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, i am trying to set those values as follows,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}



self.productAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
self.productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
    self.productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);

}
else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
{

    self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
    self.productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
}
else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
{

    self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
    self.productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);

}




self.productAmountLabel.text = @"Amount:";
self.productAmountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

//    self.productAmountTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]];
//    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

self.productAmountTextLabel.text = amountArray[indexPath.row];
self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];


tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;



[cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountTextLabel];

//    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
//    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.0f);
//    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
//    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
//[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

return cell;
```

}

The problem is that, the `productAmountTextLabel` has got the same value in both first and second row of the `UITableView`. How can I rectify it?

Following is my full code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
    //
    //    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@"Shipment Tracking System"];

    NSArray *titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Pending",@"Completed", nil];
    NSArray *icons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pending-60@2x.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Complete-60@2x.png"], nil];
    segmentedControl = [[URBSegmentedControl alloc]initWithTitles:titles icons:icons];


    if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(73, 121, 180, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(100, 121, 180, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(126, 121, 180, 30);

    }

    APIRequest *apiRequest = [[APIRequest alloc]init];
    apiRequest.pendingShipmentDetails ;

    segmentedControl.segmentBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86/255.0f green:199/255.0f blue:188/255.0f alpha:1];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //    NSData* data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"];
    //    NSMutableArray* arrayList = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    //    NSUInteger arrayLength = [arrayList count];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (result.count > 0) {
        int i;
        amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (i = 0; i < [result count]; i++) {
            //NSLog(@"%@", result);
            pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:i];
            //            NSLog(@"pro inv no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"]);
            //            NSLog(@"shipment no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pro inv date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"]);
            //            NSLog(@"inv no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]);
            //            NSLog(@"inv date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_date"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pl sh date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"planned_shipment_date"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pt ct %@",[pending valueForKey:@"point_of_contact"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pro %@",[pending valueForKey:@"products"]);
            //            NSLog(@"qty %@",[pending valueForKey:@"quantity"]);
            //            NSLog(@"rte %@",[pending valueForKey:@"rate"]);
            //            NSLog(@"amt %@",[pending valueForKey:@"amount"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pro imng %@", [pending valueForKey:@"product_image"]);
            //            NSLog(@"statsus %@", [pending valueForKey:@"status"]);

            // amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];
            [amountArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"]];
            [statusArray addObject: [pending valueForKey:@"status"]];
            [shipmentReferenceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]];
            [invoiceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]];

        }


        //   shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"], nil];
        // statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"status"], nil];
        //invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"], nil];
        //amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"SORRY");
    }

    //    shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cargo Onboard",@"In Production",@"Stuffing in Progress",@"In Production",@"Cargo Onboard",@"Quality Check in Progress",@"Goods received for Shipment", nil];
    //    invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cargo Onboard",@"In Production",@"Stuffing in Progress",@"In Production",@"Cargo Onboard",@"Quality Check in Progress",@"Goods received for Shipment", nil];

    // invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@", arrayList[i][@"invoiceNumber"],nil];

    //    statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cargo Onboard",@"In Production",@"Stuffing in Progress",@"In Production",@"Cargo Onboard",@"Quality Check in Progress",@"Goods received for Shipment", nil];



    self.completedOrdersTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *v = [UIView new];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return v;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [shipmentReferenceNumberArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [indexPath row] + 200;
}

//- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)])
//    {
//        CGFloat cornerRadius = 10;
//        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
//        CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
//        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
//        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 0, 0);
//
//        BOOL addLine = NO;
//        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1)
//        {
//            CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
//        }
//        else if (indexPath.row == 0)
//        {
//            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
//            addLine = YES;
//        }
//        else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
//            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
//            addLine = YES;
//        }
//        layer.path = pathRef;
//        CFRelease(pathRef);
//        //set the border color
//        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
//        //set the border width
//        layer.lineWidth = 1;
//        layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
//
//
//        if (addLine == YES) {
//            CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
//            CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
//            lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width, lineHeight);
//            lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
//            [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
//        }
//        UIView *testView;
//        testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
//        [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
//        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
//        cell.backgroundView = testView;
//    }
//
//}

- (void)handleSelection:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    if (selectedSegment == 0)
    {
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        [self.myOrdersTableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.completedOrdersTableView setHidden:YES];

        NSLog(@"hoi");
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


        NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        if (result.count > 0) {
            NSManagedObject *pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:1];


            NSLog(@"statsus %@ %@", [pending valueForKey:@"status"], [pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]);


        }

    }
    else
    {
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        [self.completedOrdersTableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.myOrdersTableView setHidden:YES];
    }
}





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    UILabel *productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    self.proformaInvoiceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentStatusLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentStatusDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.invoiceDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.invoiceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedDateTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    self.productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productQuantityLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productQuantityTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productRateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productRateTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        self.proformaInvoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(85, 20, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 40, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(88, 60, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(35, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(92, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(122, 80, 100, 30);
        self.productImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 60, 60);
        self.productNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 100, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productRateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productRateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(102, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
        self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150, 170, 200, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        self.proformaInvoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(85, 20, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 40, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(88, 60, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(35, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(92, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(122, 80, 100, 30);
        self.productImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 60, 60);
        self.productNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 100, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productRateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productRateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(102, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
        self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.frame = CGRectMake(205, 170, 200, 30);
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        self.proformaInvoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(85, 20, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 40, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(88, 60, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(35, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(92, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(122, 80, 100, 30);
        self.productImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 60, 60);
        self.productNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 100, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productRateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productRateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(102, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
        self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.frame = CGRectMake(234, 170, 200, 30);

    }



    self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.text = @"Shipment Ref. #:";
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.text = @"shipment_ref_no";
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productNameLabel.text = @"products";
    self.productNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10];

    self.productAmountLabel.text = @"Amount:";
    self.productAmountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.text = @"amount";
    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i<[shipmentReferenceNumberArray count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"as %@",amountArray[i]);
    }
    NSLog(@"huhuhu %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]]);

    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]];
    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    productAmountTextLabel.text = amountArray[indexPath.row];
    productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productQuantityLabel.text = @"Quantity:";
    self.productQuantityLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productQuantityTextLabel.text = @"quantity";
    self.productQuantityTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.invoiceLabel.text = @"invoiceNumber";
    self.invoiceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.invoiceDateLabel.text = @"invoiceDate";
    self.invoiceDateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.proformaInvoiceLabel.text = @"shipment_ref_no";
    self.proformaInvoiceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];



    self.shipmentStatusLabel.text = @"Cargo Shipped";
    self.shipmentStatusLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic" size:10];

    self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.text = @"shipped date";
    self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedDateLabel.text = @"ETD:";
    self.estimatedDateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedDateTextLabel.text = @"etd";
    self.estimatedDateTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.text = @"/ ETA:";
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.text = @"eta";
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BioMass Pellets.jpg"];


    self.productRateLabel.text = @"Rate:";
    self.productRateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productRateTextLabel.text = @"USD 100";
    self.productRateTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.text = @"Shipped by Vaighai World Wide";
    self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10];

    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.proformaInvoiceLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentStatusDateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentStatusLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.invoiceDateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.invoiceLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedDateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedDateTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productNameLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productQuantityLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productQuantityTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productRateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productRateTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productAmountTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel];
    //    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    //    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.0f);
    //    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    //    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    //[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // NSLog(@"you have selected %d",indexPath.row);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Where is productAmountTextLabel defined?

Comment: it is defined as ` self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
` within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: the problem is in your for loop in first code block - on each step of the loop you create new NSMutableArray,  so it should contatins only the last pending value, doesn.t it?

Comment: You are creating a new `statusArray` and `amountArray` for each iteration of your loop. I suspect what you want is to create the arrays outside then loop and add the new values inside the loop. Also it is probably much cleaner to store a single array of NSManagedObjects and access the two fields in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` rather than maintaining multiple arrays

Comment: @Ivan I have externalised  amount array outside the for loop but still the same problem persists

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please elaborate? thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, remove for loop. because if your are executing for loop in cellForRowAtIndexPath then always last value will be display in each cell.

```
  self.productAmountTextLabel.text = amountArray[i];
    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];
```

Comment: ok but amountArray[i] requires "i" which Im inheriting from for loop. How can i sort this out without for loop?

Comment: use indexPath.row instead of i

Comment: it displays the tag %@

Comment: if amountArray contains nsnumber object then [NSString StringWithFormat:"%@",ammountArray[indexPath.row]]

Comment: i used  `  self.productAmountTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]];`
  but the same `%@` is being displayed bro

Comment: Im filling it like  `   amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];`

Comment: uh :(   it should be like this amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106994/discussion-between-user31231234124-and-saood).

Comment: ok thank you...it prints the number by now but still the last number is printed twice and first number is missing

Comment: i have posted the entire cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: Please use Autolayout instead of define frames w.r.t devices. and also make iboutlet for label in cell and and also define identifier for reuse cell. the approach you are following is very bad and outdated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];


        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


        NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


        if (result.count > 0) {
    statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < [result count]; i++) {
                NSManagedObject *pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:i];

                [statusArray addObject: [pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]];
                [amountArray addObject: [pending valueForKey:@"amount"]];
            }
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

     UILabel *productAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    UILabel *productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {

        productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {

        productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);

    }




    productAmountLabel.text = @"Amount:";
    productAmountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]];
    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    productAmountTextLabel.text = amountArray[indexPath.row];
    productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];


    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;



    [cell.contentView addSubview:productAmountLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productAmountTextLabel];

    //    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    //    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.0f);
    //    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    //    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    //[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

Following is my full code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
    //
    //    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@"Shipment Tracking System"];

    NSArray *titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Pending",@"Completed", nil];
    NSArray *icons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pending-60@2x.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Complete-60@2x.png"], nil];
    segmentedControl = [[URBSegmentedControl alloc]initWithTitles:titles icons:icons];


    if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(73, 121, 180, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(100, 121, 180, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(126, 121, 180, 30);

    }

    APIRequest *apiRequest = [[APIRequest alloc]init];
    apiRequest.pendingShipmentDetails ;

    segmentedControl.segmentBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86/255.0f green:199/255.0f blue:188/255.0f alpha:1];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //    NSData* data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"];
    //    NSMutableArray* arrayList = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    //    NSUInteger arrayLength = [arrayList count];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (result.count > 0) {
        int i;
        amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (i = 0; i < [result count]; i++) {
            //NSLog(@"%@", result);
            pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:i];
            //            NSLog(@"pro inv no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"]);
            //            NSLog(@"shipment no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pro inv date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"]);
            //            NSLog(@"inv no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]);
            //            NSLog(@"inv date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_date"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pl sh date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"planned_shipment_date"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pt ct %@",[pending valueForKey:@"point_of_contact"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pro %@",[pending valueForKey:@"products"]);
            //            NSLog(@"qty %@",[pending valueForKey:@"quantity"]);
            //            NSLog(@"rte %@",[pending valueForKey:@"rate"]);
            //            NSLog(@"amt %@",[pending valueForKey:@"amount"]);
            //            NSLog(@"pro imng %@", [pending valueForKey:@"product_image"]);
            //            NSLog(@"statsus %@", [pending valueForKey:@"status"]);

            // amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];
            [amountArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"]];
            [statusArray addObject: [pending valueForKey:@"status"]];
            [shipmentReferenceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]];
            [invoiceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]];

        }


        //   shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"], nil];
        // statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"status"], nil];
        //invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"], nil];
        //amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@",[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"SORRY");
    }

    //    shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cargo Onboard",@"In Production",@"Stuffing in Progress",@"In Production",@"Cargo Onboard",@"Quality Check in Progress",@"Goods received for Shipment", nil];
    //    invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cargo Onboard",@"In Production",@"Stuffing in Progress",@"In Production",@"Cargo Onboard",@"Quality Check in Progress",@"Goods received for Shipment", nil];

    // invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"%@", arrayList[i][@"invoiceNumber"],nil];

    //    statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Cargo Onboard",@"In Production",@"Stuffing in Progress",@"In Production",@"Cargo Onboard",@"Quality Check in Progress",@"Goods received for Shipment", nil];



    self.completedOrdersTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *v = [UIView new];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return v;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [shipmentReferenceNumberArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [indexPath row] + 200;
}

//- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)])
//    {
//        CGFloat cornerRadius = 10;
//        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
//        CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
//        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
//        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 0, 0);
//
//        BOOL addLine = NO;
//        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1)
//        {
//            CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
//        }
//        else if (indexPath.row == 0)
//        {
//            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
//            addLine = YES;
//        }
//        else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
//            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
//            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
//            addLine = YES;
//        }
//        layer.path = pathRef;
//        CFRelease(pathRef);
//        //set the border color
//        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
//        //set the border width
//        layer.lineWidth = 1;
//        layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
//
//
//        if (addLine == YES) {
//            CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
//            CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
//            lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width, lineHeight);
//            lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
//            [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
//        }
//        UIView *testView;
//        testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
//        [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
//        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
//        cell.backgroundView = testView;
//    }
//
//}

- (void)handleSelection:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    if (selectedSegment == 0)
    {
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        [self.myOrdersTableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.completedOrdersTableView setHidden:YES];

        NSLog(@"hoi");
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


        NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        if (result.count > 0) {
            NSManagedObject *pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:1];


            NSLog(@"statsus %@ %@", [pending valueForKey:@"status"], [pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]);


        }

    }
    else
    {
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        [self.completedOrdersTableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.myOrdersTableView setHidden:YES];
    }
}





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    UILabel *productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    self.proformaInvoiceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentStatusLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentStatusDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.invoiceDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.invoiceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedDateTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    self.productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productQuantityLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productQuantityTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productRateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productRateTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.productAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS || IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        self.proformaInvoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(85, 20, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 40, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(88, 60, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(35, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(92, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(122, 80, 100, 30);
        self.productImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 60, 60);
        self.productNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 100, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productRateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productRateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(102, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
        self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150, 170, 200, 30);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        self.proformaInvoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(85, 20, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 40, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(88, 60, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(35, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(92, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(122, 80, 100, 30);
        self.productImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 60, 60);
        self.productNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 100, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productRateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productRateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(102, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
        self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.frame = CGRectMake(205, 170, 200, 30);
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        self.proformaInvoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(85, 20, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 30);
        self.invoiceDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 40, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 100, 30);
        self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(88, 60, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedDateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(35, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(92, 80, 100, 30);
        self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(122, 80, 100, 30);
        self.productImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 60, 60);
        self.productNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 100, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productQuantityTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, 115, 100, 30);
        self.productRateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productRateTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(102, 130, 100, 30);
        self.productAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 145, 100, 30);
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(117, 145, 100, 30);
        self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.frame = CGRectMake(234, 170, 200, 30);

    }



    self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.text = @"Shipment Ref. #:";
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.text = @"shipment_ref_no";
    self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productNameLabel.text = @"products";
    self.productNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10];

    self.productAmountLabel.text = @"Amount:";
    self.productAmountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.text = @"amount";
    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i<[shipmentReferenceNumberArray count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"as %@",amountArray[i]);
    }
    NSLog(@"huhuhu %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]]);

    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",amountArray[indexPath.row]];
    //    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    productAmountTextLabel.text = amountArray[indexPath.row];
    productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productQuantityLabel.text = @"Quantity:";
    self.productQuantityLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productQuantityTextLabel.text = @"quantity";
    self.productQuantityTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.invoiceLabel.text = @"invoiceNumber";
    self.invoiceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.invoiceDateLabel.text = @"invoiceDate";
    self.invoiceDateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.proformaInvoiceLabel.text = @"shipment_ref_no";
    self.proformaInvoiceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];



    self.shipmentStatusLabel.text = @"Cargo Shipped";
    self.shipmentStatusLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic" size:10];

    self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.text = @"shipped date";
    self.shipmentStatusDateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedDateLabel.text = @"ETD:";
    self.estimatedDateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedDateTextLabel.text = @"etd";
    self.estimatedDateTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.text = @"/ ETA:";
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.text = @"eta";
    self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BioMass Pellets.jpg"];


    self.productRateLabel.text = @"Rate:";
    self.productRateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.productRateTextLabel.text = @"USD 100";
    self.productRateTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.text = @"Shipped by Vaighai World Wide";
    self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10];

    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.proformaInvoiceLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentReferenceNumberLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentStatusDateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.shipmentStatusLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.invoiceDateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.invoiceLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedDateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedDateTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedTimeArrivalLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.estimatedTimeArrivalTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productNameLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productQuantityLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productQuantityTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productRateLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productRateTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:productAmountTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.vaighaiWorldWideLabel];
    //    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    //    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.0f);
    //    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    //    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    //[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // NSLog(@"you have selected %d",indexPath.row);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: still the same problem persists

Comment: Put the debugger in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check what exactly the amountArray contains.

Comment: amountarray contains two values exactly

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot of the array showing the objects.

Comment: i have added the screenshot

Comment: Check the edited method of cellForRowAtIndexPath. Use this method. As you are declaring the label globally, that might be causing the problem

Comment: still the same problem is persisting

Comment: if you can share the code I can help you out. Else its difficult to tell you more.

Comment: can you zip the code and share it on github or dropbox and share the link.